# Partial Fraction Decomposition of $\frac{1}{x^2(x^2+25)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I have been reviewing some integration techniques and have been searching for tough integrals with solutions online. When I was going through the solution, however, I found a discrepancy between my solution and theirs and think what I did was correct instead.

I am trying to solve the indefinite integral: $\int\frac{dx}{x^2(x^2+25)}$. My first step was to break it into the fractions $$\frac{1}{x^2(x^2+25)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+25}$$ Then multiplying both sides by $x^2(x^2+25)$, we find our basic equation to be$$1=A*x(x^2+25)+B*(x^2+25)+(Cx+D)*x^2$$ Solving the system of linear equations, I found that $B=\frac{1}{25}$, $D=\frac{-1}{25}$, and $A=C=0$.

This is where I found the discepancy. The online solution has the basic equation as $$1=A*x(x^2+25)+B*(x^2+25)+(Cx+D)*x$$ so when they solve for coefficients they find that $B=\frac{1}{25}$, $C=\frac{-1}{25}$, and $A=D=0$.

Am I correct or are they? And if my answer is incorrect how does one of the $x$'s cancel out from the $(Cx+D)$ term? Thanks for any help!

Comment: At least for these question where there are only two expressions in denominator of same degree, it can be directly split out as $\displaystyle\frac{1}{25}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+25}\right) $.

Comment: If you're not shy of manipulating complex numbers, a fairly easy check is to plug in $x=5i$ and see if you get $1$ on the right hand side.  That will tell you right away which answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Here's an other proof:

If we put $X=x^2$ then

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2(25+x^2)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{X(25+X)}$$
$$=\frac{B}{X}+\frac{D}{25+X}$$

$$Xf(x)=B+\frac{DX}{X+25}$$
with $ X=0$, it gives $ B=\frac{1}{25}$

$$(X+25)f(x)=\frac{B(X+25)}{X}+D$$
with $ X=-25$, we get $D=-\frac{1}{25}$

thus

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{25}\Bigl(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{25+x^2}\Bigr)$$

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me crazy trying to figure out where I went wrong.. so interesting that the website was wrong. Definitely gonna make me think twice before trusting any website for correct solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since the central theme is to assist in the evaluation of an integral another method is to consider the following.

$$ \frac{1}{x^2 \, (x^2 + 5^2)} = \frac{1}{25} \, \left( \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2 + 5^2} \right) $$
and
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2 + 5^2} &= \frac{A}{x - 5 \, i} - \frac{B}{x + 5 \, i} \\
&= \frac{(A-B) \, x + (A + B) \, 5 \, i}{x^2 + 5^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{10 \, i} \, \left( \frac{1}{x - 5 \, i} - \frac{1}{x + 5 \, i} \right).
\end{align}

Now,
$$ \frac{1}{x^2 \, (x^2 + 5^2)} = \frac{1}{25 \, x^2} - \frac{1}{250 \, i} \, \left( \frac{1}{x - 5 \, i} - \frac{1}{x + 5 \, i} \right) $$
and
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \, (x^2 + 5^2)} &= \int \left( \frac{1}{25 \, x^2} - \frac{1}{250 \, i} \, \left( \frac{1}{x - 5 \, i} - \frac{1}{x + 5 \, i} \right) \right) \, dx \\
&= - \frac{1}{25 \, x} + \frac{i}{250} \, \ln\left(\frac{x - 5 \, i}{x + 5 \, i} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{5^3} \, \left( \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{x}\right) - \frac{5}{x} \right) + c_{0} \\
&= \frac{1}{5^3} \, \left( \cot^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{5}\right) - \frac{5}{x} \right) + c_{0}
\end{align}